# Question URL auto-parsing stopped working?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

In [When is Attack On Titan set?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66558/when-is-attack-on-titan-set/66559#66559) I link to [When and where does Attack on Titan take place?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/when-and-where-does-attack-on-titan-take-place)

This would normally auto-parse to the Question title, but it is not. Unlike here, where both the M&TV.se and the Anime.se links auto-parsed. On my question, it does not. But a url to another question on M&TV did.

Is this a bug or is it not implemented for these two sites?

Comment: I believe you URLs only auto-parse for links back to the site you're currently on, not another Stack Exchange site (except on here).  So a URL to Anime on Movies and TV won't auto-parse.